# Собрать PHP с патчем

Tags: php, debian

Мне требуется для запуска OpenSSL ГОСТа на PHP пересобрать его с добавлением строки

> OPENSSL_config(NULL);

в файле "ext/openssl/openssl.c". Вставляю строку в данный файл в нужное место и выполняю команды:

> ./configure --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql --with-curl --enable-intl
>   --enable-mbstring=all
>
> make
>
> make install

Версия PHP обновляется, все работает, но в итоге все равно выдает

> error:0609E09C:digital envelope routines:PKEY_SET_TYPE:unsupported
>   algorithm

Я так понимаю все не так просто с патчами на Debian и просто добавить строку в файл недостаточно?
Версия PHP 5.4, на сервере Debian 7 с Apache.

Comment: Сама по себе строка OPENSSL_config(NULL); не добавит поддержку какого-либо алгоритма.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, посмотрите в историю вопросов пользователя — openssl уже сконфигурирован.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в любом случае указанная строка не добавляет поддержку каких либо алгоритмов и у меня есть стойкие сомнения что openSSL-таки собран корректно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну, автор вопроса утверждал (в первом вопросе), что с openssl всё в порядке. там, собственно, и настраивать-то почти нечего — интернет полон инструкций. а вот насчёт php, судя по моим поискам (ещё после первого из вопросов) — насколько я понял, «всё очень плохо».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin OpenSSL собран нормально, и через консоль все работает. Данная строка фигурирует во всех решениях PHP+ГОСТ, просто PHP изначально работает не с тем конфигурационныv файлом, вот например: http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/curl-и-ГОСТ.74854/